# Is it possible to have duplicate TCP option headers present on the same packet?

Tags: tcp

RFC1323 defines the TCP timestamp option.  It does not define a limit on the number of options you can have present.

Would a firewall drop a packet that has more than one TCP timestamp option header present?

Would a router drop a packet with more than one TCP timestamp?

e.g.
TCP Header | Timestamp option | Timestamp option | NOP | EOL

Comment: Probably not.  Firewalls almost never look at the options.

Comment: To clarify - not is it possible, is it allowed?

Comment: Anything that doesn't violate the RFC is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :).The RFC is ambiguous. It doesn't say if two or more of the same is allowed.  Additionally, there is what is in the RFC and then there are how different implementations / devices perform.

Comment: Exactly my point